# Переношу каталог tmp на новый раздел

Tags: linux, opensuse, fstab

В наличие каталог **tmp** по умолчанию в корневом разделе.

**/etc/fstab :**

```
UUID=c0fb1af3-08cc-4b0f-b3fa-525b47dc9006  /           btrfs  defaults             0  0
UUID=c0fb1af3-08cc-4b0f-b3fa-525b47dc9006  /var        btrfs  subvol=/@/var        0  0
UUID=c0fb1af3-08cc-4b0f-b3fa-525b47dc9006  /usr/local  btrfs  subvol=/@/usr/local  0  0

UUID=c0fb1af3-08cc-4b0f-b3fa-525b47dc9006  /tmp        btrfs  subvol=/@/tmp        0  0

UUID=c0fb1af3-08cc-4b0f-b3fa-525b47dc9006  /srv        btrfs  subvol=/@/srv        0  0
UUID=c0fb1af3-08cc-4b0f-b3fa-525b47dc9006  /root       btrfs  subvol=/@/root       0  0
UUID=c0fb1af3-08cc-4b0f-b3fa-525b47dc9006  /opt        btrfs  subvol=/@/opt        0  0
UUID=a5bbb91e-fdd9-11e8-80b9-5404a6839ffd  /home       ext4   data=ordered         0  2
UUID=fc6b0671-eace-4358-ad49-9adfb287c799  /boot       ext4   data=ordered         0  2
UUID=CE87-0A85                             /boot/efi   vfat   defaults             0  2
UUID=cf14220a-aeb3-4a77-95b0-ab7f122e7f8e  swap        swap   defaults             0  0
```

Я выделил новый **raid** раздел для него. В **Yast** выглядит так :

- Файловая система: BtrFS
- Точка монтирования:
- Монтировать по:
- Метка:
- UUID: 5092848c-a713-4bd7-ab30-4cdf6a2692ec
- RAID Level: SINGLE
- Metadata RAID Level: DUP

Подскажите как правильно подправить файл **fstab** без падающего исхода. Что за маркировка `subvol=???`, что такое `defaults`, что именно надо написать? (***swap** и **home** уже в рейде.*)

Comment: Во всех дистрибутивах _/tmp_ — это ramfs. По второму вопросу — документация на btrfs читана?

Comment: Нашёл только совет на файловую систему **tmpfs**. Не знаю как переделать. А что с остальным делать? @0andriy

Comment: _tmpfs_ — надстройка над ramfs по сути.

Comment: Как форматировать в **tmpfs** не могу догадаться. В **yast** только ext2 ext3 ext4 btrfs fat xfs swap udf @0andriy

Comment: Где-то нашёл советчиков, что предлагают такое : `UUID=5092848c-a713-4bd7-ab30-4cdf6a2692ec /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0` А как raid форматнуть в tmpfs так и не нашёл. @0andriy

Comment: Это память! Какое форматирование?! :) Просто запись в fstab и всё. (В системах с `systemd` вообще ою этом беспокоиться не стоит как я понимаю, т..к. он сам монтирует tmpfs под каждого пользователя, а /tmp можно смело оставить маленькой (и в памяти).

Comment: `tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=26382984k 0 0`, например.

Comment: Если не делаешь чего-то тяжелого) у меня тут пару раз темп заканчивался на сервере. пришлось перемонтировать

Comment: tmpfs - файловая система, существующая только в памяти (ОЗУ). На диске она отсутствует. С учётом того, что согласно стандарту иерархии файловой системы - /tmp содержит данные, которые не должны сохраняться между перезагрузками, то хранить его в памяти - логично и удобно. Так что если объёмы свободного ОЗУ позволяют - монтируйте /tmp в /tmpfs

Answer (score 0):

Опытным путём, полным крахом пробными попытками изменить другую систему, реализовал перенос директории `/tmp` из корневой системы на другой **raid** раздел.

Смотрим на каком устройстве находиться корневая система.

$ sudo lsblk

```
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
...
sdc         8:32   0 119,2G  0 disk  
├─sdc1      8:33   0    10G  0 part  
│ └─md127   9:127  0    10G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
...
└─sdc3      8:35   0  99,8G  0 part  /
```

`/` находиться на `/dev/sdc3`.

Читаем `UUID` нового раздела, куда нужно перенести директорию `tmp`.

$ sudo blkid

```
...
/dev/md127: UUID="cf14220a-aeb3-4a77-95b0-ab7f122e7f8e" TYPE="swap"
/dev/md126: UUID="5092848c-a713-4bd7-ab30-4cdf6a2692ec" TYPE="btrfs"
/dev/md2: UUID="a5bbb91e-fdd9-11e8-80b9-5404a6839ffd" TYPE="ext4"
```

Новый раздел для `/tmp` отформатированный под `btrfs` имеет номер `UUID="5092848c-a713-4bd7-ab30-4cdf6a2692ec"`.

Добавляем строку в `/etc/fstab` пока-что комментарием :

```
# UUID=5092848c-a713-4bd7-ab30-4cdf6a2692ec  /tmp        btrfs  defaults             0  0
```

Берём загрузочный диск, перезагружаемся им и заходим в `Rescue System`.

```
rescue login : root
mount /dev/sdc3 /mnt
/mnt/usr/bin/nano /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Закомментируем старые записи, раскомментируем новые :

```
# UUID=c0fb1af3-08cc-4b0f-b3fa-525b47dc9006  /tmp        btrfs  subvol=/@/tmp        0  0
UUID=5092848c-a713-4bd7-ab30-4cdf6a2692ec  /tmp        btrfs  defaults             0  0
```

Переименовываем старую директорию `tmp`, потом почистим.

```
mv /mnt/tmp /mnt/tmpold
reboot
```

Вот и переселился. Насчёт хранения временных файлов в памяти пока не готов.